# WPF DatePicker does not use Material Design's style

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, styles, material-design

I am using MaterialDesignThemes in my WPF project and I am able to see MaterialDesign styles being used by various WPF controls I am using. In one particular situation, however, I'm having a great bit of difficulty trying to get a DatePicker to use the MaterialDesign styling. When I render DatePickers in a XAML view, it works as expected. The difference is that in the case that it does not work, the date picker is rendered in code behind. Below is my code. Can anyone help?

```
var dp = new DateControl()
{
     Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, _fontSize, 0),
     HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
     Question = q,
     IsReadOnly = IsReadOnly || q.IsReadOnly
};
if (dataValue != null)
{
     DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
     if (DateTime.TryParse(dataValue, out dt) && dt > DateTime.MinValue)
     {
           dp.SetSelectedDate((DateTime?)dt);
    }
    else
    {
         dp.Text = dataValue;
    }
}
if (!IsReadOnly)
    dp.AddHandler(DateControl.LostFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(HandleUserResponse));

MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.ColorZoneAssist.SetMode(dp, ColorZoneMode.PrimaryDark);

return dp;
```

Comment: What is a "DateControl"?

Comment: DateControl is a class that inherits a DatePicker. If I instantiate a DatePicker directly then the style shows up fine. When I do not, it seems to want to use the default windows system control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `Style` property of your custom control:

```
dp.Style = FindResource("MaterialDesignDatePicker") as Style;
```

`MaterialDesignThemes` doesn't know what a `DateControl` is and won't automatically apply any style to such a control. The implicit style that is applied to `DatePicker` controls is not inherited.

Comment: Thank you mm8! That did it. I cannot upvote your answer because of low reputation points, but as soon as I have enough I will return to all my questions and upvote the correct answer. Once again, thank you so much for pointing this out to me. As you can see in my original code, I attempted to set the style but I was doing it totally wrong.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to accept an answer as well!